# Template and custom function; err: executing "templName" at <"funcName"> is not a define function

Tags: go, go-templates

I got some text that I´m adding with template.AddParseTree method in order to append the template text, but there is a weir behaviour, the method is supossed to use it like this:

```
singleTemplate=anyTemplate
targetTemplate=*template.Must(targetTemplate.AddParseTree(e.Name, anyTemplate.Tree))
```

But is not working when singleTemplate has a funtion, by a weird reason it only works when I do this

```
singleTemplate=anyTemplate
targetTemplate=*template.Must(singleTemplate.AddParseTree(e.Name, anyTemplate.Tree))
```

But it must not work that way, because I won´t be able to append anything else
You can try it here: https://play.golang.org/p/f5oXNzD1fKP

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var funcionIncremento = template.FuncMap{
    "inc": func(i int) int {
        return i + 1
    },
}

func main() {

    var strs []string
    strs = append(strs, "test1")
    strs = append(strs, "test2")
    //-----------------Not valid(it would)
    var probar1 = template.Template{}
    var auxiliar1 = template.Template{}
    auxiliar1 = *template.Must(template.New("test").Funcs(funcionIncremento).Parse(`
            {{range $index, $element := .}}
                Number: {{inc $index}}
            {{end}}
    `))

    probar1 = *template.Must(probar1.AddParseTree("test", auxiliar1.Tree))
    err := probar1.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "test", &strs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error1: ", err)
    }
//--------------------------------valid(it wouldn´t), because I wouldn´t be able to append
    var probar2 = template.Template{}
    var auxiliar2 = template.Template{}
    auxiliar2 = *template.Must(template.New("test").Funcs(funcionIncremento).Parse(`
            {{range $index, $element := .}}
                Number: {{inc $index}}
            {{end}}
    `))

    probar2 = *template.Must(auxiliar2.AddParseTree("test", auxiliar2.Tree))
    err = probar2.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "test", &strs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error2: ", err)
    }
    //-------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.AddParseTree("t", b.Tree)` adds *only* the `parse.Tree` of template `b` it does not add `b`'s functions because they are not part of the `parse.Tree` type, they are part of the `template.Template` type.

Any function that `b` needs to use, must also be added to `a`.

```
var probar1 = template.New("pro").Funcs(funcionIncremento)
var auxiliar1 = template.New("aux").Funcs(funcionIncremento)

auxiliar1 = template.Must(auxiliar1.Parse(`
        {{range $index, $element := .}}
            Number: {{inc $index}}
        {{end}}
`))

probar1 = template.Must(probar1.AddParseTree("test", auxiliar1.Tree))
err := probar1.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "test", &strs)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error1: ", err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! also, that cause an error, the line: var auxiliar1 = template.New("aux").Funcs(funcionIncremento), it does not work, because you have to add the function to  [https://play.golang.org/p/X_xhKIJVmQ4](https://play.golang.org/p/X_xhKIJVmQ4) auxiliar1 = template.Must().Funcs(funcionIncremento)

Comment: It fails because in that example you've created a new template `template.New("test)` that does not have the functions and called `Parse` on that, instead of on `auxiliary1` which already has the functions. See this: https://play.golang.org/p/EIJGZ5OJqoi

Comment: To clarify a bit more @JohnBalvinArias, `var auxiliar1 = template.New("aux").Funcs(funcionIncremento)` does not cause the error, it's `Parse` causing it. `Parse` parses the given string and everytime it encounters a function, e.g. `inc` it will check if that function is present in the `template.Template` on which `Parse` was called and if it isn't present it will return an error. You can see that more clearly here: https://play.golang.org/p/y5m6k1TMjWK